# FIlter the list with a condition in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j

Suppose I have a table of this sort

```
| Type                    | Name           | Status   |
| --------                | -------------- | -------- |
| ["Thriller" , "Horror"] | Conjuring      | Released | 
| ["Action" , "Thriller"] | Evil Dead      | Released |
| ["Drama" , "Thriller"]  |   XYZ          | Released |
```

I want to retrieve the rows that are not Thriller. In other words I want to do something like  `Type.filter(item => item != "Thriller")`
How can I do this in Neo4J?

Expected Result

```
| Type     | Name           | 
| -------- | -------------- |
| "Horror" | Conjuring      |     
| "Action" | Evil Dead      |      
| "Drama"  |   XYZ          |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cypher has a list comprehension syntax:

```
[x in type WHERE x <> "Thriller" | x]
```

Find more info in docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use APOC, the function is called: apoc.coll.removeAll

Syntax: apoc.coll.removeAll([first], [second]) - returns "first" list with all elements of "second" list removed

> Ref:
> https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.removeAll/

```
 RETURN apoc.coll.removeAll(Type, "Thriller") as Type, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this feature using this piece of cypher query

`RETURN DISTINCT [x in Type WHERE x <> "Thriller"][0] as Type`

Comment: if movie has three categories, which one will you use? Let's say  Romance, Comedy, Thriller

Comment: Yes you are right. I should make it more generic. I did [0] because in my case its always Array of size 2